# I'd like my question re-opened please

Tags: discussion

I asked the following question: [Are there any instances of an individual whose Animagus form is a magical creature?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/are-there-any-instances-of-an-individual-whose-animagus-form-is-a-magical-creature)

It was closed as a duplicate of

[Can an Animagus take the form of any animal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/can-an-animagus-take-the-form-of-any-animal), likely due to **@DVK**'s answer here, which included the following:

> *There was also never any mention of Animagus form being a magical animal. But it's unlikely you will obtain magical powers foreign to you even if you self-Transfigure yourself into the form of a Phoenix or Unicorn.* - DVK

The premise of my question distinguishes between regular animals and magical animals -- I am not lumping them all together. Because  @DVK has not found a reference to a magical animal that serves as an Animagus doesn't  mean it doesn't exist. I note, and @DVK agreed with me, that the statement in question is not based in canon and is not referenced. Basically, it's an opinion, not an answer, and there is a distinction between a regular animal (giraffe, horse, stag) and a magical creature (Kappa, Augury, HORKLUMP!).

I truly think the two questions are distinctive enough that they are not duplicates. I would really like to have my question re-opened: [Are there any instances of an indivdual whose Animagus form is a magical creature?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/are-there-any-instances-of-an-individual-whose-animagus-form-is-a-magical-creature)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have used my powers as Time-Lord to do what's requested several days ago.

Comment: I thank you and your TARDIS! :D

Answer (score 7):

Unless I'm much mistaken, it *was* reopened, by HP Gold Tag badge holder @DVK on Sep 16 at 19:00.

Comment: +1 because My Duh. :D

Comment: Wait ... I have a gold tag badge in *Harry Potter* ... I can reopen questions by myself as well?

Comment: @Slytherincess - Yes, you can. Where they're closed as dupes, at least.

Comment: @Slytherincess You can close them by yourself as well  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/266359

Comment: @Slytherincess - use the Badge, Luke!

Comment: @Slytherincess -Swish and ... flick - "*Alohomora*"